# A weird bug in my code is causing some strange results, I believe it's due to my use of fork

Tags: c++, bash

There are a few different strange results that result from different types of input. First off, I'm building a simple linux shell, and below I show some example i/o

```
$ 
$ 
$ 
$ ls -l /
$ $ exit
```

so the first thing you probably notice is the double $. This happens whenever I have entered something into the prompt and not simply left it blank. Second, it appears to have exited properly, as it returns control back to my terminal... or does it? I really don't know, but as I'm in my terminal, if I simply press enter, this pops up in my terminal.

```
finn-and-jake@CandyKingom:~/Desktop/OS/hw2$ terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::at
```

I'm not 100% what's causing this or how to fix it, but I have a hunch that it has something to do with fork, and I believe that's also what's causing my extra $. There's also another issue with when I put input in as I did above, but with some empty input between the initial and the exit, which results in the program not completely closing out. An example is provided below.

```
$ 
$ 
$ ls -l /
$ $ 
$ 
$ 
$ 
$  
$ 
$ 
$ exit

$ exit
```

and finally, there's another issue that I'm not sure what's causing it where the program runs in an infinite loop I can't force quit out of and it crashes my operating system (Ubuntu 14.04)

In an attempt to keep the code minimal, I'm only including the method that I suspect to be the cause of this. If any more than that is requested I will include it in an edit.

```
void Shell::interpreteInput() {
        if (commandQueue.empty()) {
                return;
        };

        if (commandQueue.at(0) == "exit") {
                exit = true;
                return;
        };

        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
                cerr << "Fork unsuccessful\n";
                return;
        };
        if (commandQueue.size() >= 3 && commandQueue.at(commandQueue.size() - 2) == ">") {
                //commandQueue.at(commandQueue.size() - 1) is fileName          open


                //commandQueue.at(0) is name of program to run                  exec 
                //remaining substrings are args
        };

        //commandQueue.at(0) is name of program to run                          exec
        // remaining substrings are args

};
```

Edit (response to first question in comments): In the child process, execute the given program, passing it the given arguments (if any).  If the program is a bare name (i.e., it does not contain any slashes), search the PATH for the executable.  If the line has form 1 (my fourth if statement) —where the output is to be redirected—open (create or overwrite) a file with the given path, and redirect the program’s output to that file.  (See detailed instructions below.)

• If output is to be redirected but the file cannot be opened, display an error message and return to Step 1.

• If the given program cannot be executed (exec fails), display an error message and return to Step 1.

Comment: Are you waiting for the forked process to return in the parent? It's not clear from your code if you are.

Comment: You need to have separate code paths for the parent and child process. The parent should wait until all child processes are finished before exiting.

Comment: @KurtStutsman good question, I'm not really sure myself I'm very new to all of this. The following is the instructions I was given... actually I'll put it in an edit.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that would be more checks to see if the pid > 0 for the parent and pid == 0 for the child correct? And then have the execvp function in the child to make the input execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you're using a function like `waitpid()` or one of the related wait functions in the parent process. When `fork()` returns successfully (not -1), there are two processes running. The parent process will return the actual PID of the child process. The child process will get a return value of 0. So you need code like this:

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == -1) {
   // handle error
} else if (pid == 0) {
   // do child process stuff
} else {
   // do parent process stuff
   int status, rc;
   do {
       rc = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
       // handle rc value from waitpid
   } while (!WIFEXITED(status));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain what the rc value is?

Comment: It's the typical C system call errno return. The [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) describes the return codes for the function.

Comment: As @wallyk also pointed out in his answer, the `waitpid()` portion is only valid for foreground processes. If you're going to do background processes, you'll have to handle those differently. You'll still need to wait on the process once it exits to prevent zombie processes.

Comment: @ZachThompson FYI I updated the code snippet slightly. It should be `WIFEXITED(status)`.

Comment: Thanks man, I've actually got it working now. I just have to add like 5 more lines and it should be good.

Answer (score 2):

After `fork()`, there is a check for a fork error, but otherwise both parent and child process do the same thing afterwards.  You probably want to diverge code paths:  parent does one thing and child does another.

Traditionally, a shell parent process waits for the child process to complete, unless there is an `&` indicating that the parent does not wait.  The child then scoops together the command pipe line and `exec`'s the command(s).